# removing metadata from jpegs created with imagecreatetruecolor() on php without external libraries

Tags: php, image, jpeg, exif

On my website, I create images at 69% quality with the image GD library. It attaches the following meta-tag into each image I create:

"CREATOR: gd-jpeg v1.0 (using IJG JPEG v62), quality = 69"

Because my website has several hundred thousand JPEG images, people would be downloading at least 30MB of nonsense just to see every pic.

I want to somehow successfully erase this metatag and all other unnecessary junk in the JPEG files without resorting to any more libraries. Even some binary solution would be good if I can find one.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Having an image stripped of metadata upon upload in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/676951/having-an-image-stripped-of-metadata-upon-upload-in-php)

Comment: `jhead -purejpg`, `mogrify -strip`, `exiftool -all=`